# Xamarin Azure Active Diretory Redirect URI Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a Xamarin app that needs to authenticate the user over Azure AD, I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Client nugget for this.

The app is able to go to the microsoft SSO page, but after hit login button the page returns the error: **AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: [ApplicationID]**

App Class:

```
    public static string ClientID = [ApplicationID];

    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };
    public static string Username = string.Empty;

    public static UIParent UiParent { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PCA = new PublicClientApplication(ClientID);
        PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{App.ClientID}://auth";
        //PCA.RedirectUri = $"AppSGA://auth";
        
        MainPage = new Paginas.Login();
    }
```

in the fourth line in the constructor, if I use PCA.RedirectUri = "AppSGA://auth"; instead of PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{App.ClientID}://auth";
it won't return errors but the sso page will be loading forever without any response.

Login method in login page:

```
 private async void ADLogin()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

        try
        {
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes, firstAccount);
            await UserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, App.UiParent);

                await UserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

On Azure the app was registered with:

**Name: AppSGA**

**Application Type: Native**

**Redirect URi: AppSGA://auth**

App Manifest on Azure:

```
   {
  "appId": AppID,
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": true,
  "displayName": "AppSGA",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,
  "homepage": null,
  "informationalUrls": {
    "privacy": null,
    "termsOfService": null
  },
  "identifierUris": [],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": true,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "objectId": [ObjectId],
  "parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
  },
  "passwordCredentials": [],
  "publicClient": true,
  "replyUrls": [
    "AppSGA://auth"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": resourceAppId,
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": id,
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": resourceAppId
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": id,
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: There is something wrong with the redirect uri. Redirect URI is a scheme and string combination that Azure AD uses to return token responses. Enter a value (for example, http://DirectorySearcher).

Comment: Hi Tony, I changed de URI for http://DiretorySearcher in the app and Azure, but did not work either, same error

Comment: The redirect url should be the one which should show after the user login. Can you debug to see the value of the redirect url in the request url?

Comment: I cannot debug in .AcquireTokenAsync() but if i do it before it goes to this line the uri returns http://DirectorySearcher

Comment: You can use fiddler to capture the request.

Comment: Cool, it gave me two URLs, http://login.microsoftonline.com:443 before hit login button, after hit the button http://aadcdn.msauth.net:443

Comment: Can you find any request like https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3a12345
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7?

Comment: No, nothing like that

Comment: Well, based on the error message, the redirect url does't match. You can change the redirect url to https://www.baidu.com to have a try. Both in your code and azure portal.

Comment: I've set the microsof site, the page navigated to It after login, but the page didn't close and returned user info haha. For while I will stick with the normal AD authentication, if I have any progress on the SSO I will post here. Tks anyway

Comment: That is correct, you just need to change the redirect url to your userinfo page. Then after login, you will navigate to the correct page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PCA.RedirectUri = $"msal{App.ClientID}://auth";` is the format of the default redirectUri for Xamarin Android and iOS when using MSAL.

Here's [documentation on setting up the redirectUri for public clients](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications#redirect-uri-for-public-client-applications).

If you're using Android, in the AndroidManifest.xml, you'll need to include the following:

`<data android:scheme="msal{client_id}" android:host="auth" />`

Here's more [info on setting up Xamarin Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-Android-specifics#ensuring-control-goes-back-to-msal-once-the-interactive-portion-of-the-authentication-flow-ends) and [iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-iOS-specifics#implement-openurl)

Also, you should consider updating to MSAL v3.x. Here's a link to the [blog post](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-3-released#configuring-an-app-got-simpler) which outlines how to migrate to the new builder pattern for creating the public client and handling the acquire token calls.

Comment: @rodrigo.cantunes awesome!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because the reply URL configured in the portal is not the same as the one specified by your app. This must be an exact match.

Here is a tutorial for fixing this. It is for App Services but the same steps apply.: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2018/01/30/azure-app-service-error-aadsts50011-the-reply-address-http-azurewebsites-netsignin-oidc-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application/

It does take a few minutes for this change to propegate sometimes- I've been caught fairly often because I change this setting in AAD but think that it has not been fixed because it does not start working immediately.